# Removing SDLKey references in iOS project

Tags: c++, ios, c, input, sdl-2

recently I have started work on porting an SDL game to iOS. I've gotten the game into Xcode, and I've got the required SDL libraries compiled and linked (SDL2-2.0.8, SDL2_mixer-2.0.2, and SDL2_image-2.0.3). The biggest problem I have though is this:

```
Unknown type name 'SDLKey'
```

And I have no idea how to replace all of the references. Is there a way I can just 'null' out all the references so I can at least compile without input?

Comment: What language, C or C++? If C, just typedef it to `int`.

Comment: can you post what are you trying to compile? or at least a minimal example that reproduces your problem

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In SDL 2 SDLKey equivalent is SDL_Keycode.